# Joomla component category develop

Tags: components, joomla3.5

After i follow joomla "Developing an MVC Component" Document until step 15- "Adding ACL"

```
Link - https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_ACL
```

everything works,

but i didn't see anything about create frontend category view,so i add a new view "category",here is my code:

in admin fields folder,i create a hellocategory.php
most code same with helloword,just change

```
protected $type = 'HelloCategory';

/**
 * Method to get a list of options for a list input.
 *
 * @return  array  An array of JHtml options.
 */
protected function getOptions()
{
    $db    = JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    // custom
    $query->select('#__categories.id as id,#__categories.title as category,#__categories.extension as exten');
    $query->from('#__categories');  
    $query->where($db->quoteName('extension') . ' LIKE '. $db->quote('com_helloworld'));
    // end custom
    $db->setQuery((string) $query);
    $messages = $db->loadObjectList();
    $options  = array();
```

view.html.php

```
class HelloWorldViewCategory extends JViewLegacy
{
    /**
     * Display the Hello World view
     *
     * @param   string  $tpl  The name of the template file to parse; automatically searches through the template paths.
     *
     * @return  void
     */
    function display($tpl = null)
    {
        // Assign data to the view
        $category = $this->get('Item');

        // Check for errors.
        if (count($errors = $this->get('Errors')))
        {
            JLog::add(implode('<br />', $errors), JLog::WARNING, 'jerror');

            return false;
        }

        // Display the view
        parent::display($tpl);
    }
}
```

default.xml

```
<layout title="Category">
        <message>category</message>
</layout>
<fields
        name="request"
        addfieldpath="/administrator/components/com_helloworld/models/fields"
        >
    <fieldset name="request">
        <field
                name="id"
                type="hellocategory"
                label="COM_UNOFD_UNOFD_FIELD_GREETING_LABEL"
                description="COM_UNOFD_UNOFD_FIELD_GREETING_DESC"
                />
    </fieldset>
</fields>
```

default.php

```
<?php var_dump($category); ?>
```

nothing output,
is there anything about create category document or sample online?i tried google for solution four days,but still no idea, or the only way is get data from database?

Answer (score 0):

Closed,

because i found Joomla stackExange,thanks!

the question move to

```
http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/17475/joomla-3-helloworld-component-category
```